# Javascript Promise undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, callback, promise

I am new to Javascript and AngularJS, I am trying to figure this out.
I made an angular service that execute DB queries and return promise.

```
        executeStatement = function(db, sql, values, onsuccess, onerror) {
        if (!!db.executeSql) {
            return db.executeSql(sql, values || [], onsuccess, onerror);
        } else {
            return db.transaction(function(tx) {
                return tx.executeSql(sql, values, function(ignored, rs) {
                    return onsuccess(rs);
                }, function(ignored, error) {
                    return onerror(error);
                });
            });
        }
    };

    this.executeStatement = function(sql, values) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready( function() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                return executeStatement(myDB, sql, values, resolve, reject);
            });
        } );
    }
```

And then If I call the executeStatement like this in the angular service module.

```
    this.extract = function(callback) {
        _DB.executeStatement('SELECT * FROM FRIDGE', []).then(callback);}
```

Shouldn't this return a promise after the functions are finished running?
I'm getting undefined :(
Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does `$ionicPlatform.ready` return a `Promise`?

Comment: Now i made it return Promise, but it looks like the actual DB query gets finished way after, so Promise doesn't contain any db data.... What should I do?

Comment: _"but it looks like the actual DB query gets finished way after, so Promise doesn't contain any db data"_ Which DB query? Not sure what you mean by "way after"? Do you mean at `return db.executeSql(sql, values || [], onsuccess, onerror)`, which is not passed to `onsuccess` or `onerror`?  Why are there two functions named `executeStatement`?

Comment: yes... I'd like the executesql to be completely finished before moving on

Comment: Can you include text of `.executeSql` function at Question? Do you call `onsuccess` or `onerror` within the function? The functions passed would be callbacks,  yes? You are returning a function, not a `Promise` `if (!!db.executeSql)`? Though you do pass `resolve`, `reject` to the function.

Comment: executeSql is just websql function, and when I call executeStatement, I'd like it to return Promise object with DB rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions within `executeStatement` are not `Promise`, do not need to be `return`ed, where `onFulfilled`, `onRejected` of `Promise` constructor is passed as parameters to a function, if and when `onsuccess`, `onerror` are called, the original `Promise` will be resolved or rejected.

Include second parameter to chained `.then()` or use `.catch()` to handle potential errors within `Promise` chain.

Not sure if `$ionicPlatform.ready` returns a `Promise`?

```
  _executeStatement = function(db, sql, values, onsuccess, onerror) {
    if (!!db.executeSql) {
        // `onsuccess` or `onerror` need to be called for `Promise`
        // to be fullfiled; a value needs to be passed to 
        // `onsuccess` or `onerror` to get the value at `.then()` or `.catch()`
        db.executeSql(sql, values || [], onsuccess, onerror); 
    } else {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(sql, values, function(ignored, rs) {
                onsuccess(rs);
            }, function(ignored, error) {
                onerror(error);
            });
        });
    }
  };
```

```
this.executeStatement = function(sql, values) {
    return $ionicPlatform.ready( function() {
             return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
               _executeStatement(myDB, sql, values, resolve, reject);
             })
             .catch(function(err) {
               // handle, pass error here
               console.log(err);
               return err
             })
           });
}
```

```
this.executeStatement(/* parameters */)
.then(function success(data) {
  console.log(data);
}, function err(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I accepted your answer, I'm still stuck, When I add a log just before onsuccess(rs); this log comes after the console.log(data)

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I still dont get why console.log(data) gets run before anything in excutesql... When I added log statement before onsuccess(rs), it still comes after

Comment: What is text of `.executeSql` function?

Comment: I'm really not sure, im just following this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Comment: What is expected result of `!!db.executeSql`?

Answer (score 1):

The `this.executeStatement()` function needs to return the result of `$ionicPlatform.ready()`:

```
this.executeStatement = function(sql, values) {
    return $ionicPlatform.ready( function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            return executeStatement(myDB, sql, values, resolve, reject);
        });
    } );
}
```

Now you can access whatever's returned from `executeStatement` in your callback, which you can pass in as the argument to the `.then()` function:

```
_DB.executeStatement('SELECT * FROM FRIDGE', []).then(callback);
```

Comment: Thank you!
So, if I want to work with the results, the list of objects, in the callback function, what should I do?

Comment: have updated answer to include how to use `callback` - just pass into `.then()` the definition of the function w/o invoking it

Comment: Thank you! but I want to call the callback function after all the DB queries are finished. It looks like it's not the case here...